# Android - Mostrar círculo de carga mientras se carga una actividad de Google Maps

Tags: java, android, spinner

Tengo una aplicación con una actividad principal (MainActivity). En ella hay un botón de Empezar que, al pulsarlo, pasa a otra actividad (AugmentedRealityAct). En esta, a su vez, hay un menú. Uno de sus items es GoogleMaps y al pulsarlo inicia una tercera actividad de Google Maps (MapsActivity). Sin embargo, cuando pulsamos esa opción del menú, se queda congelado unos segundos hasta que lanza la actividad de mapa. Me gustaría poder poner un típico círculo de carga mientras se lanza, pero no sé cómo hacerlo.

Pongo el trozo de código de AugmentedRealityAct en el que llama a la actividad de Google Maps:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {//Se crea el menú
    Log.v(TAG, "onOptionsItemSelected() item="+item);
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.showRadar:
            showRadar = !showRadar;
            item.setTitle(((showRadar)? "Hide" : "Show")+" Radar");
            break;
        case R.id.showZoomBar:
            showZoomBar = !showZoomBar;
            item.setTitle(((showZoomBar)? "Hide" : "Show")+" Zoom Bar");
            zoomLayout.setVisibility((showZoomBar)?LinearLayout.VISIBLE:LinearLayout.GONE);
            break;
        case R.id.exit:
            finishAffinity();
            break;
        case R.id.maps:
            startIntent=new Intent(AugmentedRealityAct.this,MapsActivity.class);
            startActivity(startIntent);
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Y también la actividad de mapa:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private Context context=this;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    DataBaseHelper db;

    LatLngBounds spain = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(35.13, -15), new LatLng(44.98, 5.99));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(spain, 0));
    mMap.setLatLngBoundsForCameraTarget(spain);
    mMap.setMinZoomPreference(5.4f);

    mMap.setContentDescription("Google Map with polylines.");

    LocalDataSource localData = new LocalDataSource(this.getResources());//Se crea una instancia de la clase LocalDataSource
    db=localData.getDataBase(context);

    Cursor nombreruta = db.nombreruta();

    for (nombreruta.moveToFirst(); !nombreruta.isAfterLast(); nombreruta.moveToNext()) {
        int i=0;

        Cursor airway = db.waypoints(nombreruta.getString(0));

        ArrayList<LatLng> coordList = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        for (airway.moveToFirst(); !airway.isAfterLast(); airway.moveToNext()) {
            coordList.add(new LatLng(airway.getDouble(1), airway.getDouble(2)));
            BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw=(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.waypoint);
            Bitmap b=bitmapdraw.getBitmap();
            Bitmap smallMarker=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b,30,30,false);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(airway.getDouble(1), airway.getDouble(2))).title(airway.getString(0)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)).anchor(0.5f,0.5f));
            if (i>=1){
                LatLng latlng1=coordList.get(i-1);
                LatLng latlng2=coordList.get(i);
                double lat1=latlng1.latitude;
                double lng1=latlng1.longitude;
                double lat2=latlng2.latitude;
                double lng2=latlng2.longitude;
                LatLng imag=new LatLng((lat2-lat1)/2,(lng2-lng1)/2);


                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(imag).title(nombreruta.getString(0)).snippet(nombreruta.getString(0)));
            }
            i=i+1;

        }
        mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().addAll(coordList).width(5).color(Color.BLUE));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la clase declaras:

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;
```

En el metodo onCreate() agregas lo siguiente:

```
   progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
  progressDialog.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
  progressDialog.setMessage("Cargando...");
  progressDialog.show();
```

Acabas de crear tu dialogo y ya se muestra, ahora solo debes quitarlo cuando el mapa este cargado.

Para esto agrega el siguiente codigo en el metodo onMapReady() *o en caso de que lo utilizes en otro lugar lo agregas en el metodo que define la carga completa* y preferiblemente al final de todo:

```
 progressDialog.dismiss();
```

En tu código quedaría de esta forma:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback
 { 
 private GoogleMap mMap;
 private Context context=this;
 ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

 {

  progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this); 
 progressDialog.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher); 
 progressDialog.setMessage("Cargando..."); 
 progressDialog.show();

 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps); // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used. 
 SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager() .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
  mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

  }

  @Override 
 public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) 
 { 
 mMap = googleMap;
 DataBaseHelper db;
 LatLngBounds spain = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(35.13, -15), new LatLng(44.98, 5.99));
  mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(spain, 0));
  mMap.setLatLngBoundsForCameraTarget(spain);
  mMap.setMinZoomPreference(5.4f);
  mMap.setContentDescription("Google Map with polylines.");
 LocalDataSource localData = new LocalDataSource(this.getResources());//Se crea una instancia de la clase LocalDataSource
  db=localData.getDataBase(context);
 Cursor nombreruta = db.nombreruta();
 for (nombreruta.moveToFirst(); !nombreruta.isAfterLast(); nombreruta.moveToNext()) 
 { 
 int i=0; 
 Cursor airway = db.waypoints(nombreruta.getString(0)); 
 ArrayList<LatLng> coordList = new ArrayList<LatLng>(); 
 for (airway.moveToFirst(); !airway.isAfterLast(); airway.moveToNext())
 { 
 coordList.add(new LatLng(airway.getDouble(1), airway.getDouble(2)));

 BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw=(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.waypoint); 
 Bitmap b=bitmapdraw.getBitmap(); 
 Bitmap smallMarker=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b,30,30,false);
 mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(airway.getDouble(1), airway.getDouble(2))).title(airway.getString(0)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)).anchor(0.5f,0.5f));

 if (i>=1){ 

 LatLng latlng1=coordList.get(i-1); 
 LatLng latlng2=coordList.get(i);
 double lat1=latlng1.latitude;
 double lng1=latlng1.longitude; 
 double lat2=latlng2.latitude; 
 double lng2=latlng2.longitude;
 LatLng imag=new LatLng((lat2-
 lat1)/2,(lng2-lng1)/2); 
 mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(imag).title(nombreruta.getString(0)).snippet(nombreruta.getString(0)));

 }
 i=i+1; 

 }
 mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().addAll(coordList).width(5).color(Color.BLUE));

 progressDialog.dismiss();

 } 

 }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero no me deja ponerlo como "final". Lo he puesto como "private" y no sale nada.

Comment: Simplemente quita el final

Comment: Ya lo actualize

Comment: Sigue sin salirme nada. Adjunto vídeo: https://youtu.be/WQ_By9YHQp8         Cuando le doy a "Mapa" tarda unos segundos hasta que se abre el mapa, pero sigue sin salir lo de "Cargando...".

Comment: Lo volvi a actualizar ahora declaro final pero dentro del onCreate() , ahi te lo dejo

Comment: Si lo meto dentro, el dismiss ya no funciona porque progressDialog ya no es una variable global...

Comment: Cierto, veré que puedo hacer.

Comment: Creo que como cargar de forma asíncrona no aplica porque como estaba la primera vez me funciona en otros proyectos

Comment: Intenta poniendo el dismiss tambien dentro del onCreate(), pero al final.